# How do I log into sites properly with Python's requests?

Tags: python, authentication

I have been through numerous Google results and Stack Overflow questions trying to figure out how to do the following. Most have suggested the use of requests' session class to store session information.

Unfortunately none of the solutions provided worked with any of the sites I have tried. Obviously I'm doing something wrong and I want to figure out what that is before I drive myself crazy.

My current code:

```
from requests import session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

USER = 'leinad177'
PASSWORD = '' # removed for obvious reasons

URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin'

with session() as s:
    login_data = {'wpName': USER,
                  'wpPassword': PASSWORD}

    r = s.post(URL, data=login_data)
    r = s.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences')

    print bs(r.text).find('div', {'id':'mw-content-text'}).p.text.strip()
    # "Please log in to change your preferences."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some POST parameters. wpLoginToken is probably the only one that is mandatory.

```
wpLoginAttempt:Log in
wpLoginToken:...
wpForceHttps:1
```

Also, the correct URL is:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&action=submitlogin&type=login
```

wpLoginToken is not static, and you will have to parse it with beautifulsoup before logging in.

How to get the token:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

s = requests.session()
URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin'

req = s.get(URL).text
html = bs(req)

wp_login_token = html.find("input", {"name": "wpLoginToken"}).attrs['value']
```

Comment: Would you be able to go into more detail about retrieving the wpLoginToken?

Comment: I have edited my post and added how to get the token.